# C: how to allow sscanf to keep white spaces in front of string?

Tags: c, whitespace, fgets, scanf

Hey guys so I am trying to do the following:

I have a string of the form and the _ are actually spaces.:

**__ 1 *_*__**_Multithreaded Programming :: Improving Performance through Threads

I want to read the integer **without** spaces, and then read the remainder of the string **including** the space that will be in front of the string.

I have the following code:

```
while(fgets(line, MAX_STRINGS, stdin)){
    sscanf(line, "%d %88[^\n]s", &num, string_value);
    printf("%d + %s\n", num, string_value);
}
```

It reads the integer and also it reads the rest of the string ( My requirements for the problem state that the whole string including the integer will not be more than 88 bytes) BUT it ommits all the spaces in front of the string and I need them. How can I keep the white spaces? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `s` in `%d %88[^\n]s`.  Remove the space also.  Check result of `2 == sscanf()`.  If the sizeof(string_value) is 88, then use `%d%87[^\n]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between %d and %88. A space in the `sscanf` format string means "consume and discard all whitespace".

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you very much for your help! It worked like a charm and also fixed a problem that I was going to have to deal with later, not knowing how lol ! Thank you!